# CryptographicException ID1073 error The is invalid on ASP.NET 4.0 site

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, cookies, forms-authentication, wif

Has anyone ever come across this error? I'm getting this when I post back to a forms authenticated site after redirecting to another site and then redirecting back. I've already checked that loadUserProfiles="true" but that did not help. This is a site hosted on IISExpress via other sites also hosted on IISExpress, using localhost gen'ed SSL certs and differentiating via host header.  I'm pretty clueless at this point on where the error even comes from. Is it a cookie error? The FormsAuth cookie? It's ASP.NET 4.0 site where I'm authenticating against a Thinktecture Id server. Any feedback is appreciated to help me with my current block. Thanks

### Server Error in '/' Application.

The data is invalid.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The data is invalid.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[CryptographicException: The data is invalid.
]
   System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Byte[] encryptedData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope) +318
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Decode(Byte[] encoded) +203

[InvalidOperationException: ID1073: A CryptographicException occurred when attempting to decrypt the cookie using the ProtectedData API (see inner exception for details). If you are using IIS 7.5, this could be due to the loadUserProfile setting on the Application Pool being set to false. ]
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Decode(Byte[] encoded) +319
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ApplyTransforms(Byte[] cookie, Boolean outbound) +217
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +1951
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(Byte[] token, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +149
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.ReadSessionTokenFromCookie(Byte[] sessionCookie) +595
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(SessionSecurityToken& sessionToken) +120
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +113
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18044

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crypto errors like this are common if your application pool is **not** set to load its user profile. The crypto system needs to access user's cert store.

The exact moment the error occurs is when you authenticate and the sts sends back the signed SAML token.

This means that the error is subtle. You don't see it everytime, only in one exact moment. You can even be deceived that the error is gone because the site works correctly, however the error reappears as soon as someone tries to log in.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was only happening in IE9 when running in Debug mode. After awhile it went away for whatever reason. :/

Comment: I am also seeing this error show up only in IE9 and intermittently. I have yet to duplicate it myself, so it is proving to be difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: it's occurring with me on Google Chrome

Comment: I was able to reproduce it in one environment by deleting the second part xor first part of the FedAuth cookie.